# In Python Session how do I know the filds that are to be posted to Request Payload at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, python-responses

I'm logging in on to a webpage using the Session in Python, where the 2FA is enabled.

```
self.response = self.session.post(login_url,
                                  data={"email": self.email, "password": self.password},
                                  headers=self.session.headers)
```

[image]

By using the above code I'm able to log in to the webpage successfully, because I know the data it is asking for i.e., `email` & `password`. After this it redirects me the the 2FA page, where it is asks for the security questions (NOTE: There are total 10 security questions). At runtime it selects any 2 random questions.

[image: 2FA]

Like in the above picture it asked me to enter the answer of  `"questionId": "6"` & `"questionId": "10"`.

So, my problem is how do I know that for which questionId's answer it is asking for? So that I post the answer's data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape the security question asked each time and then pass the request the corresponding answer.